# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component in Carousel component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm building Carousel Component using useLayoutEffect. this useLayoutEffect hook has been set in `resizeWindow.ts` separately. and resizeWindow function is called in functional Component named `carousel`. I can't find where breaking rule is.

```js
//resizeWindow.ts 

  import { useLayoutEffect, useState, RefObject } from 'react'

/***
 * @function resizeWindow
 * this function is custom hook for grab resizing innerWidth of element.
 * 
 * 
 */
export const resizeWindow: (ref: RefObject<HTMLElement>) => number[]  = (ref) => {
  const [ elementWidth, elementHeight ] = ref.current ?  
    [ref.current.offsetWidth, ref.current.offsetHeight ] :
    [0,0];
  const [size, setSize] = useState([elementWidth, elementHeight]);
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const updateSize = () => {
      setSize([elementWidth, elementHeight]);
      console.log(`elementWidth: ${elementWidth}px`);
    };
    updateSize(); 
    window.addEventListener('resize', updateSize);

    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', updateSize);
  },[]);
  return size;    
};

//carousel.ts
//

import { resizeWindow } from './resizeWindow.ts'; 

export const Carousel: FC = ({
  children
}) => {
  const parentRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null); 
  const slideRef = createRef<HTMLDivElement>(); 

  const [count, setCount ] = useState<number>(0); 
  const [parentWidth, setParentWidth] = resizeWindow(parentRef); 

  const total = React.Children.count(children); 
  const nextSlide = () => {
    if( count < total -1 ){
      setCount( count + 1 );
    } else if( count === total-1 ){
      setCount(1); 
    }
  }
  const prevSlide = () => {
    if( count > 0 ){
      setCount( count -1 );
    } else if( count === 0 ){
      setCount(total -1 );
    }
  }
  useEffect(()=> {
    console.log('parentRef: ', parentRef); 
    if(slideRef.current){
      slideRef.current.style.transition = "all 0.5s ease-in-out";
      slideRef.current.style.transform = `translateX(-${count}00%)`;
    }
    if(parentRef.current){
      resizeWindow(parentRef);
    }
  },[count || parentWidth])
  return(
    <SliderContainer ref={parentRef}>
      <Slider ref={slideRef} width={parentWidth * total}>
        {children}        
      </Slider>   
      <Indicator now={1} total={total}/>
      <Button onClick={prevSlide}>left</Button>
      <Button onClick={nextSlide}>right</Button>
    </SliderContainer>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resizeWindow is a custom hook, you should not be using it inside useEffect hook. This usage is what gives you an error.

Also you must name your custom hooks by prefixing their name with `use`

Also you must destructure ref properties within the updateSize function in resizeWindow hook so that you don't face the closure problem within updateSize function

The updated solution will look like

```
export const useResizeWindow: (ref: RefObject<HTMLElement>) => number[]  = (ref) => {
  const [size, setSize] = useState([elementWidth, elementHeight]);
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const updateSize = () => {
      const [ elementWidth, elementHeight ] = ref.current ?  
       [ref.current.offsetWidth, ref.current.offsetHeight ] :
       [0,0];
      setSize([elementWidth, elementHeight]);
      console.log(`elementWidth: ${elementWidth}px`);
    };
    updateSize(); 
    window.addEventListener('resize', updateSize);

    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', updateSize);
  },[]);
  return size;    
};
```

and its usage will be as follows

```
//carousel.ts
//

import { useResizeWindow } from './resizeWindow.ts'; 

export const Carousel: FC = ({
  children
}) => {
  const parentRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null); 
  const slideRef = createRef<HTMLDivElement>(); 

  const [count, setCount ] = useState<number>(0); 
  const [parentWidth, setParentWidth] = useResizeWindow(parentRef); 

  const total = React.Children.count(children); 
  const nextSlide = () => {
    if( count < total -1 ){
      setCount( count + 1 );
    } else if( count === total-1 ){
      setCount(1); 
    }
  }
  const prevSlide = () => {
    if( count > 0 ){
      setCount( count -1 );
    } else if( count === 0 ){
      setCount(total -1 );
    }
  }
  useEffect(()=> {
    console.log('parentRef: ', parentRef); 
    if(slideRef.current){
      slideRef.current.style.transition = "all 0.5s ease-in-out";
      slideRef.current.style.transform = `translateX(-${count}00%)`;
    }
  },[count || parentWidth])
  return(
    <SliderContainer ref={parentRef}>
      <Slider ref={slideRef} width={parentWidth * total}>
        {children}        
      </Slider>   
      <Indicator now={1} total={total}/>
      <Button onClick={prevSlide}>left</Button>
      <Button onClick={nextSlide}>right</Button>
    </SliderContainer>
  )
}
```

Comment: Plz let me ask one thing.  Is custom hook a only wrong usage in other hooks like useEffect ? can setState can use in useEffect ?

Comment: you can use setState in useEffect because that isn't a hook. According to the rules of hooks, hooks can be called conditionally or within other functions. If you think about it, your custom hook contained useLayoutEffect and so it would mean that you are calling useLayoutEffect within `useEffect` which is a violation